# Laravel return eloquent result where it matches all ids not just a couple

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I can't wrap my head around this for some reason even though it seems the answer is right in front of me.

I have 3 tables, `rentals`, `amenities`and `amenities_rentals`

Amenities are things like air conditioning, staff ect.

The `amenities_rentals` has `rentail_id`, `amenities_id`. This table is basically a reference table that connects `rentals` to `amenities`.

In a search a user can narrow down rentals by checking off certain amenities. As of now its giving me all the rentals that have at leas one of the checked off options. I need it to narrow down to only rentals that have **ALL** of the chosen amenities. This is what I have, this is not only not pulling the info correct but I know there is a better way to do it.

```php
if($request->has('amenities')) 
{
    $rental_ids = AmenitiesRentals::select('rental_id')
                    ->whereIn('amenities_id',$request->amenities)
                    ->distinct()
                    ->get();
    $builder->whereIn('rentals.id', $rental_ids->toArray());
}
```

The rest of the builder works fine.

Answer (score 5):

As Kamal Paliwal suggested, define a `BelongsToMany` relationship in your `Rental` model:

```php
public function amenities() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Amenity::class, 'amenities_rentals', 'rental_id', 'amenities_id');
}
```

Then use `whereHas()`:

```php
$amenities = $request->amenities;

$rentals = Rental::whereHas('amenities', function ($query) use ($amenities) {
    $query->whereIn('amenities.id', $amenities);
}, '=', count($amenities))->get();
```

Comment: this works for me only when there are more than 1 amenities selected. When I select a single amenity, I still got rentals with multiple amenities..

Comment: @user3253002 The query selects all rentals that have *at least* the selected amenities. In your case, you need to add a `has('amenities', '=', count($amenities))` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a many relationship between rentals and amenities like below:

```
public function amenities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\AmenityModel::class, 'amenities_rentals', 'rental_id', 'amenities_id');
}
```

Then while applying filter you can add it in this way:

```
$amenitiesIds = $request->amenities;
RentalsModel::with('amenities')->whereHas('amenities', function ($q) use ($amenitiesIds) {
    $q->whereIn('amenities_id', $amenitiesIds);
})
```

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Hi Kamal, what does country_user in your example refer to?

Comment: It was something related to my code. I have updated it check now.

Comment: This does not solve the problem instead, it will rental model object instead of the rental id.

Comment: You can fetch the id's from its collection

Answer (score 0):

You should select rentals that has the count of amenities ids same as the size of amenities array from your request by grouping rentals by amenities count.

Here is an example:

```
$amenities_ids = $request->amenities;
$amenities_ids_count = count($amenities_ids);

$rental_ids = AmenitiesRentals::selectRaw("COUNT(amenities_id) as amenities_count, rentail_id")
                ->whereIn('amenities_id', $amenities_ids)
                ->groupBy('rentail_id')
                ->having('amenities_count', $amenities_ids_count)
                ->get();
```